# Example of non-nuclear C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

A C*-algebra $A$ is called *nuclear* iff there is a unique cross C*-norm on the algebraic tensor product $A\otimes B$ for any other C*-algebra $B$. It is equivalent that the minimal (spatial) and maximal norms on $A\otimes B$ coincide.

I know (cf. [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221367/simple-and-non-nuclear-c-algebra)) that an example of a non-nuclear C*-algebra ist $C_r^\ast(\mathbb F_2)$ where $\mathbb F_2$ is the free group on two generators and $C_r^\ast(\mathbb F_2)$ denotes its reduced group C*-algebra.

Now my question is: Is there an *explicit* example of a C*-algebra $B$ such that the minimal and maximal norms on $C_r^\ast(\mathbb F_2)\otimes B$ do not coincide? With *explicit* I mean that one can write down both norms and see that they are different, e.g. by evaluating them on some specific element. Are there easier examples for other C*-algebras instead of $C_r^\ast(\mathbb F_2)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Takesaki's original proof that $C_r^*(\mathbb F_2)\otimes C_r^*(\mathbb F_2)$ admits at least two different tensor norms is as "explicit" as it can be, although it cannot explicitly calculate  norms of elements.

The problem here is with the word "explicit": it is a relative notion. You want a specific element of the tensor product. And you want an explicit calculation of its norm. As far as I can tell, with the exception of very carefully crafted trivial examples, there is no way to explicitly calculate the norm of $\sum_ja_j\otimes b_j$.

Comment: Well, this is actually very much what I thought of. Mainly, I need a simple counterexample to give at the end of a introductory talk about C*-algebras, just to show that tensor products are no trivial construction with C*-algebras.

Answer (score 2):

An answer to your second question (it depends on what you mean by "easier", however), the following $C^*$-algebra is well understood: $B(H)$ for an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is not nuclear [S. Wassermann, "on Tensor products of certain group $C^*$-algebras"].

Regards